# Need yaml dump to construct yaml file like this

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pyyaml

So I am trying to convert a mongodb document dictionary to yaml file and this is my code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps, loads
import yaml
import json
import ruamel.yaml

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)

database = client["movie_db"]

movies = database.movies


cursor = movies.find({}, { "_id": 0 })
list_cur = list(cursor)
yaml_data = yaml.dump(list_cur, explicit_start = True, explicit_end = False, sort_keys=False, indent=3)
with open('data.yaml', 'w') as file:
    file.write(yaml_data)
```

which produces data.yaml file which looks like this:

```
---
-  inventory:
      plugin: SimpleInventory
      options:
         host_file: /home/rojin/virtualP/ProjectAutomation/inventory/hosts.yaml
         group_file: /home/rojin/virtualP/ProjectAutomation/inventory/groups.yaml
   runner:
      plugin: threaded
      options:
         num_workers: '1'
- {}
```

There are characters like '-' and '{}' for some reason i dont know. I have a network automation script that takes this yaml for configuration. But using this script produces error. So I need the yaml script to looks something like this:

```
---

inventory:
    plugin: SimpleInventory
    options:
        host_file: "/home/rojin/virtualP/ProjectAutomation/inventory/hosts.yaml"
        group_file: "/home/rojin/virtualP/ProjectAutomation/inventory/groups.yaml"
        #defaults_file: "/home/rojin/virtualP/ProjectAutomation/inventory/defaults.yaml"

runner:
       plugin: threaded
       options:
            num_workers: 1
```

because this seems to be working.

Comment: Would you show `list_cur`?

Comment: Here it is:           [{'inventory': {'plugin': 'SimpleInventory', 'options': {'host_file': '/home/rojin/virtualP/ProjectAutomation/inventory/hosts.yaml', 'group_file': '/home/rojin/virtualP/ProjectAutomation/inventory/groups.yaml'}}, 'runner': {'plugin': 'threaded', 'options': {'num_workers': '1'}}}, {}]

Comment: It seems you have two documents in `movie_db.movies`.  It doesn't look much like a movie either.  :-)  And `'num_workers': '1'` has a string value - shouldn't it be an integer?  Do you want to fix your collection, or do you want to work with what you have?

Comment: oh right thanks i just realized it should be an integer. i want to fix it and also improve the yaml file like i said in the question. Could you please help?

Comment: So you are storing the YAML parameters in a movie database?

Comment: Yeah this is just for a test, I just need the yaml file to work for now. It goes into a nornir script for network automation.

Comment: Well, I don't completely understand the MongoDB usage, but if you use `yaml.dump(list_cur[0], ...` after `find`, I think you'll get what you want.

Comment: wow this was so simple, it works. Many Many thanks!!!!